# Python, trying to write a CSV file to a specific location.

Tags: python, io, writer

I am trying to write a file to a specific location, to do this I wrote the following code.

The program is in a folder on an external HDD. I have used the os.path to get the current path (I think..)

the "fileName" var is = hello
the "savePath" var is = data

When I run the code I get the following error...

IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'data\hello_23-04-2014_13-37-55.csv'

Do I need to set permissions for the file before I try to write to it? If so.. how do you do this>?

```
def writeData(fileName, savePath, data):
    # Create a filename
    thisdate = time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
    thistime = time.strftime("%H-%M-%S")
    name = fileName + "_" + thisdate + "_" + thistime + ".csv"

    # Create the complete filename including the absolute path 
    completeName = os.path.join(savePath, name)

    # Check if directory exists
    if not os.path.exists(completeName):
        os.makedirs(completeName)

    # Write the data to a file
    theFile = open(completeName, 'wb')
    writer = csv.writer(theFile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    writer.writerows(data)
```

Comment: Could it be that you don't have sufficient permissions to the *folder* you're writing to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get a different error (putting permission issues aside) when I try a stripped down version of what you're doing here:

```
>>> import os
>>> path = "foo/bar/file.txt"
>>> os.makedirs(path)
>>> with open(path, "w") as f:
...    f.write("HOWDY!")
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: 'foo/bar/file.txt'
```

Note that when you do this:

```
# Check if directory exists
if not os.path.exists(completeName):
    os.makedirs(completeName)
```

...you're creating a directory that has a name that's both the path you want (good) and the name of the file you're trying to create. Pass the pathname only to `makedirs()` and then create the file inside that directory when you've done that.

Comment: Thanks, that was the key!